# Can't upload Docker image to Artifactory - connection reset by peer

Tags: docker, artifactory

I'm trying to push a docker image to a Artifactory in the same local network but it stops after a while with that error msg:

> root@CI:/home/iggy# docker push 10.87.65.7:5000/tibco The push refers
>   to a repository [10.87.65.7:5000/tibco] da6d16ef19d5: Pushing [=>
>   ] 551.4 kB/1.519 GB write tcp 10.87.65.33:54890->10.152.254.201:8080:
>   write: connection reset by peer

I'm able to login using "docker login 10.87.65.7:5000" with admin credentials to Artifactory. I've added "10.87.65.7:5000" to insecure-registries. I can't see any error logs in nginx, however I saw some error logs in Artifactory:

> 2017-08-31 09:24:03,076 [ACCEPTED CONFIGURATION_CHANGE]  for
>   admin/10.87.65.9. 2017-08-31 09:24:19,947 [ACCEPTED
>   CONFIGURATION_CHANGE]  for admin/10.87.65.9. 2017-08-31 09:24:24,404
>   [DENIED LOGIN]  for NA/10.87.65.7. 2017-08-31 09:27:06,160 [DENIED
>   LOGIN]  for NA/10.87.65.7.

More info:

> root@CI:/home/iggy# docker -v  Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802
>   Artifactory - jfrog-artifactory-pro-5.4.6

10.87.65.7 - Artifactory VM,
10.87.65.33 - Docker VM

Any clue why is that happening?

PS. journalctl -u docker.service from 10.87.65.33:

> wrz 01 10:25:54 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:25:54.102482175+02:00" level=error msg="Handler
>   for GET /v1.24/containers/c9d96afbfa84/json returned error: No such
>   container: c9d96afbfa84" wrz 01 10:27:54 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:27:54.827236788+02:00" level=error msg="Attempting
>   next endpoint for push after error: Get https://10.87.65.7:5000/v2/:
>   Tunnel or SSL Forbidden" wrz 01 10:28:21 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:28:21.191783057+02:00" level=error msg="Upload
>   failed, retrying: write tcp 10.87.65.33:55014->10.152.254.201:8080:
>   write: connection reset by peer" wrz 01 10:28:21 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:28:21.250673504+02:00" level=error msg="Upload
>   failed, retrying: write tcp 10.87.65.33:55016->10.152.254.201:8080:
>   write: connection reset by peer" wrz 01 10:28:21 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:28:21.301091802+02:00" level=error msg="Upload
>   failed, retrying: read tcp 10.87.65.33:55022->10.152.254.201:8080:
>   read: connection reset by peer" wrz 01 10:28:21 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:28:21.321781695+02:00" level=error msg="Upload
>   failed, retrying: write tcp 10.87.65.33:55018->10.152.254.201:8080:
>   write: connection reset by peer" wrz 01 10:28:51 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:28:51.250855040+02:00" level=error msg="Upload
>   failed, retrying: read tcp 10.87.65.33:55032->10.152.254.201:8080:
>   read: connection reset by peer" wrz 01 10:28:51 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:28:51.314110199+02:00" level=error msg="Upload
>   failed, retrying: write tcp 10.87.65.33:55034->10.152.254.201:8080:
>   write: connection reset by peer" wrz 01 10:28:51 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:28:51.336208120+02:00" level=error msg="Upload
>   failed, retrying: write tcp 10.87.65.33:55036->10.152.254.201:8080:
>   write: connection reset by peer" wrz 01 10:28:51 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:28:51.357638907+02:00" level=error msg="Upload
>   failed, retrying: write tcp 10.87.65.33:55038->10.152.254.201:8080:
>   write: connection reset by peer" wrz 01 10:28:57 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:28:57.837608810+02:00" level=error msg="Upload
>   failed, retrying: received unexpected HTTP status: 502 Server Hangup"
>   wrz 01 10:29:26 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:29:26.160819971+02:00" level=error msg="Upload
>   failed, retrying: read tcp 10.87.65.33:55048->10.152.254.201:8080:
>   read: connection reset by peer" wrz 01 10:29:26 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:29:26.247001138+02:00" level=error msg="Upload
>   failed, retrying: write tcp 10.87.65.33:55050->10.152.254.201:8080:
>   write: connection reset by peer" wrz 01 10:29:26 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:29:26.345532227+02:00" level=error msg="Upload
>   failed, retrying: write tcp 10.87.65.33:55056->10.152.254.201:8080:
>   write: connection reset by peer" wrz 01 10:29:26 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:29:26.532987146+02:00" level=error msg="Upload
>   failed, retrying: write tcp 10.87.65.33:55052->10.152.254.201:8080:
>   write: connection reset by peer" wrz 01 10:30:04 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:30:04.385713563+02:00" level=error msg="Upload
>   failed, retrying: received unexpected HTTP status: 502 Server Hangup"
>   wrz 01 10:30:06 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:30:06.191469609+02:00" level=error msg="Upload
>   failed, retrying: read tcp 10.87.65.33:55070->10.152.254.201:8080:
>   read: connection reset by peer" wrz 01 10:30:06 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:30:06.215756304+02:00" level=error msg="Upload
>   failed, retrying: write tcp 10.87.65.33:55072->10.152.254.201:8080:
>   write: connection reset by peer" wrz 01 10:30:06 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:30:06.352755861+02:00" level=error msg="Upload
>   failed, retrying: write tcp 10.87.65.33:55074->10.152.254.201:8080:
>   write: connection reset by peer" wrz 01 10:30:06 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:30:06.599892629+02:00" level=error msg="Upload
>   failed, retrying: write tcp 10.87.65.33:55076->10.152.254.201:8080:
>   write: connection reset by peer" wrz 01 10:30:51 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:30:51.246752156+02:00" level=error msg="Upload
>   failed: write tcp 10.87.65.33:55092->10.152.254.201:8080: write:
>   connection reset by peer" wrz 01 10:30:51 CI dockerd[10907]:
>   time="2017-09-01T10:30:51.246859375+02:00" level=error msg="Attempting
>   next endpoint for push after error: write tcp
>   10.87.65.33:55092->10.152.254.201:8080: write: connection reset by peer"

Comment: Have a look at registry's logs and post what you find during a push.

Comment: you mean "journalctl -u docker.service" from 10.87.65.33?

Comment: did you deploy the docker registry where you're trying to push your image? How did you do that?

Comment: In Artifactory I've created local docker repository called "tibco" to which I try to push the image

Comment: ok sorry, I can't help with artifactory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a corporate firewall or something that requires the use of an HTTP Proxy? It looks like `HTTP_PROXY` may be set somewhere in this setup (on the Docker side) as the writes are being attempted to **10.152.254.201:8080** which is not your Artifactory address. That looks like a probably HTTP proxy running on 8080. Given your two machines seem to be on the same subnet, I assume you don't want the HTTP proxy set for traffic between them. The initial authentication with Artifactory fails because of this as well:

`time="2017-09-01T10:27:54.827236788+02:00" level=error msg="Attempting next endpoint for push after error: Get https://10.87.65.7:5000/v2/: Tunnel or SSL Forbidden"`

If you search on that **Tunnel or SSL Forbidden** message you will find many people talking about HTTP proxy/firewall issues.

Comment: You were right, HTTP proxy is the root cause of this issue, thanks!

Comment: I'm actually not able to recall the specific solution, however as I mentioned earlier, HTTP proxy was the root cause of this issue.